# Password-protect page and its dependencies

Tags: 7, files, users

I haved a Views-generated page, listing links to some downloadable files. The page itself is restricted to a certain role, and this obviously works ok, but I would also like to protect all the links listed on the page.

Currently, an authenticated user with a privilege to view the page, can send a working download link to anonymous user, which is not ok.

Of course, I could certainly protect the files directory with htaccess, but I would like to manage the access and session validity from Drupal.

Has anybody solved a similar setup? Are there any modules for that?

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: Ooops, forgot to mention. D7. (Updated the tags to reflect it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Webform protected downloads](http://drupal.org/project/webform_protected_downloads) seems to be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using D6, http://drupal.org/project/filefield_stats might be of help in that it would at least not allow the sending of a working link to another user.